# Using dhclient or dhcpcd to assign address for alias interface

Tags: linux, dhcp, linux-networking

I have a Linux machine with one Ethernet interface eth0 which already has one primary static address and one secondary static address (eth0:1) assigned.  I would like to use DHCP to dynamically assign a third address to eth0:2.  This is an old question and the canonical answer is, no, you can't do that; dhclient and dhcpcd don't work on alias interfaces.  See this related question "[How to request dhcp (using dhclient) on a virtual interface (i.e. eth0:1)](https://serverfault.com/questions/308811/how-to-request-dhcp-using-dhclient-on-a-virtual-interface-i-e-eth01)" for which kce's answer gives a good explanation of the fundamental impossibility.  (There's also mention there of a potential solution involving a VLAN, but this isn't an option for me.)

Now, AFAIK, the DHCP protocol doesn't care about interfaces (alias or otherwise); its job is simply to lease IP addresses to clients. So I'm thinking of trying to rig up a configuration involving dhclient or dhcpcd where they use eth0 for the packet-level communications with the local DHCP server, but then, once an address is obtained, use that address to configure eth0:2. Has anyone ever done this?  Should it be possible?  Are there pitfalls or other impossibilities I'm overlooking?  (I'm prepared to modify the dhclient or dhcpcd source if I need to, if there aren't fundamental impossibilities. I'm also prepared to use a custom dhclient-script to set up eth0:2 and its routing correctly, once I have an address.)

Comment: What on earth is going on with your network, then?

Comment: The machine is normally on a teeny-tiny isolated network with a handful of other machines and with nothing but hand-assigned 10.* and 192.168.* addresses.  But occasionally it would be useful to connect it to a larger network, and only then might DHCP come into play.

Comment: Beginning to answer my own question: It looks like lightly modifying dbclient-script to configure a specific interface -- not necessarily the primary one that dhclient used for lease negotiation -- will suffice to solve my problem.  (Now I just need to, like, actually test it.)