# VLAN over three switches

Tags: networking, security, switch, vlan, local-area-network

We are connecting three offices via fiber optics. For each office we have one switch. In each office there will be one PC which has to be isolated in a VLAN A. There will be other PCs but those three have to be in this VLAN A.

Each PC is connected to port 1 on a switch, through switch management on each switch we say on port 1 there is a VLAN A. Switches are not stackable. Will those three PCs see each other, or do we need to do something else? Will they be isolated from other traffic?

Thanks.

Comment: See [How do VLANs work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/188350/how-do-vlans-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work, you have to connect switches using their trunk ports (just set the switch-to-switch connection port to trunk mode). Then set port1 to VLAN A, and  all the other ports will stay in another VLAN (the one you have configuired now, or in a native VLAN, if nothing is configured yet).

The PCs in vlan A will then see eachother, but won't see anything else. If you want any other connections, you have to set up routing between VLANs and/or outside (internet).