# tenants are building their own server in the share office, how do I give out specific ports to them?

Tags: networking, nat, switch, port-forwarding, vlan

**Scenario:**
A couple of companies are sharing an office as a tenant.
Since I don't have much knowledge in networking, I'm not quite sure how to configure the setting of switches and routers.

However, I did some research on it and get a clear picture now on how to do a proper setup by using VLANs:

[How do VLANs work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/188350/how-do-vlans-work/188419#188419)
The example of the best answer used is pretty much my scenario. It also gives the details on setting up VLANS.

[Advice on best way to setup shared serviced office networking (VLANs etc.center)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/303055-advice-on-best-way-to-setup-shared-serviced-office-networking-vlans-etc)

> *Typically you would use L2 switches at your network end points and one L3 switch a centre. VLAN trunk all of your vlans back to the core switch and setup your router there. It is MUCH easier to manage 1 router in your core switch than an L3 router in each switch. You can use L3 switches everywhere, only enable the router at your core switch and VLAN trunk everything else.* (George1241)

**Questions:**
1) Is the sharing office nowadays still using such VLAN set up for separating tenants?

2) Some of the tenants are even building their web server and request for ports (e.g. 80/443) since there is only one public IP, how multiple companies can share a port?

Regarding the ports, for example:
Co. A has a *web server A* on 192.168.10.1:80
Co. B has a *web server B* on 192.168.20.1:80
*web server A* can be re-directed to the [Public_IP]:80
and *web server B* can be re-directed to the [Public_IP]:8080

However, when users type the website in the browser, it automatically uses port 80 (for http://).
For people who want to visit Co. B's website, they have to type in the port manually (:8080)

2.1) Instead of buying one more public address from ISP, are there any efficient way to deal with such situation?

3) For other ports, how do I deal with the tenants who request for using the same ports?

4) Are there any specifications or regulations for setting up the network in a  sharing office?

Comment: Just get more IP addresses. It will be far cheaper than the labor in maintaining port forwards for everyone and will eliminate conflicts between tenants.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is getting more IP address usually happened in office sharing nowadays? Can port-forwarding actually achieve this? As the scenario mentioned above, can users type in the website without manually type in the port?

Comment: You can set up nginx or Apache on the public IP and use their virtual hosts features to handle the port forwarding to the right servers. In HTTP/1.1 the client specifies the host name that it's trying to reach on every request, and they will use that to route to the correct tenant's server from requests to port 80.